# Windows phone 8 How to be always on one theme even if phone's theme changed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

My app is generally designed for `dark` theme, and I'm using `StaticResources` So if the user changes his phone's theme to `light` the app gets unreadable and unusable.

I tried to change manually color of each element and avoid using `StaticResources` and things like:

```
Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"
```

and `StaticResources` for font and color. But this is a hard work.

How can I globally change the theme to my app think the phone theme is dark? *(it's a windows phone 8 app)*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update** : 
Since the release of **Windows Phone 8.1**, you can set the **RequestedTheme** attribute on any control, or even at the app level to **override the Theme set by the users in the Settings**.

***Example to force the Light theme:***

*In code*, within the constructor of the App class :

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    private TransitionCollection transitions;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;

        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
    }
}
```

Or *in XAML* :

```
<Application
    x:Class="App26.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    RequestedTheme="Light"
    xmlns:local="using:App26">
</Application>
```

For the old **Windows Phone 8** application model :

It is of course recommended in the design guidelines to use the theme resources to make sure your app works with any theme and accent color.

However if you really want to force the dark theme, here is a solution provided by Rudy Huyn on his blog: http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2013/01/18/forcer-un-theme-sous-windows-phone-8/

The idea is to add a method in your App class that will override all the system brushes with the colors of the dark theme:

```
private void DarkTheme()
{
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush"]).Color = ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneRadioCheckBoxBorderBrush"]).Color = ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneContrastForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneDisabledBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x66, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneProgressBarBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x19, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextCaretBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xBF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x77, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneSubtleBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x99, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextHighContrastBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextMidContrastBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x99, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextLowContrastBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x73, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneSemitransparentBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xAA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneChromeBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x1F, 0x1F, 0x1F);

    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneInactiveBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x33, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneInverseInactiveBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneInverseBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneBorderBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xBF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
}
```

Then, in the App constructor, you check whether the Light theme is enabled, and if it is, you override the theme:

```
if ((Visibility) Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible)
{
    DarkTheme();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the phone 8.1 reference.  I needed to do RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;  But also set the background of the rootFrame to white.  That's because most of my pages don't have a background set on them.

Comment: That's not turning the background color to black for me on WP8. The text is white, but the background remains white as well. I tried a few values for `PhoneBackgroundBrush`, including `Colors.Black` and `Color.FromArgb(0xFE, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01);`, but no luck.

Answer (score 12):

I just wanted to recommend Jeff Wilcox's 'Windows Phone Theme Manager' nuget package as an easy way to implement this functionality for both light and dark themes.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneThemeManager/

Just add a function call to the App constructor:

```
ThemeManager.ToDarkTheme();
```

or

```
ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();
```

Comment: Lots more luck with this. You don't even need to NuGet it; it's very kindly comprised of [a single file (Apache licensed)](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager/blob/master/src/JeffWilcox.PhoneThemeManager/ThemeManager.cs) you can throw into your project.

Comment: careful, this doesn't work in WinRT versions (i.e. 8.1+)