# How to force windows phone 8 app to be run in light theme

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have developed a windows phone application, i want that app to be run in light theme, irrespective of what user have set. means is there any way to set a default theme for the windows phone 8 app.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Jeff Wilcox's [`ThemeManager`](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager)

Add it to your project (there is a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneThemeManager/) available) and call it from `App()` constructor.

```
public App()
{
    // Global handler for uncaught exceptions.
    UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

    // Standard Silverlight initialization
    InitializeComponent();

    // Phone-specific initialization
    InitializePhoneApplication();

    ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();

    // Other code that might be here already...
}
```

You can find usage example [on his website](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/).

Comment: which nuget package is required here ?

Comment: Did you click the link? You'll be navigated directly to the package page.

Comment: Too bad that it is not supported for windows phone 8.1

Comment: For SL for 8.1 application you can just get a source code and compile it.

Comment: For 8.1 apps, check out this http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/17/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-theme-resources/

Comment: PM> Install-Package PhoneThemeManager - to install this via nuGet

Answer (score 7):

For **Windows phone 8.1** you can use:

```
<Application
    x:Class="App26.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    RequestedTheme="Light"
    xmlns:local="using:App26">
</Application>
```

Or

```
public App()
    {
        this.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;

        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
    }
```

Source  : [Windows phone 8 How to be always on one theme even if phone's theme changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582998/windows-phone-8-how-to-be-always-on-one-theme-even-if-phones-theme-changed)

Answer (score 1):

From http://developergoodies.blogspot.nl/2012/10/force-windows-phone-theme.html

(Tested and verified; get the themes; copied from resource to prevent future inaccessibility)

**Answer**

When the UI is designed specially for the dark theme it won't look well on the light theme, or vice versa.

To prevent this the application can force the default dark or light theme.

In the application class' constructor put this code to force the dark theme:

```
if ((Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible) MergeCustomColors("/Themes/DarkStyles.xaml");
```

Or this code to force the light theme:

```
if ((Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible) MergeCustomColors("/Themes/LightStyles.xaml");
```

Anywhere in your project put this method:

```
private void MergeCustomColors(String Theme)
{
    ResourceDictionary Dictionaries = new ResourceDictionary();
    String source = String.Format(Theme);
    var themeStyles = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative) };
    Dictionaries.MergedDictionaries.Add(themeStyles);
    ResourceDictionary appResources = Current.Resources;
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in Dictionaries.MergedDictionaries[0])
    {
        SolidColorBrush ColorBrush = entry.Value as SolidColorBrush;
        SolidColorBrush ExistingBrush = appResources[entry.Key] as SolidColorBrush;
        if (ExistingBrush != null && ColorBrush != null) { ExistingBrush.Color = ColorBrush.Color; }
    }
}
```

The code assumes that the projects contains the files DarkStyles.xaml and LightStyles.xaml in a folder named Themes.

Comment: exception at the line : var themeStyles = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative) };

Comment: Did you add the `LightStyles.xaml` file to the Themes folder (as the answer describes)?

Comment: but its like making arrangement to get the result. is there any global solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Call this method in your app constructor

```
private void LightTheme()
    {
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush"]).Color = ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneRadioCheckBoxBorderBrush"]).Color = ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xDE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneContrastForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xDE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneDisabledBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x4D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneProgressBarBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x19, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextCaretBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xDE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x26, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xDE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x2E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneSubtleBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x66, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextHighContrastBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xDE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextMidContrastBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneTextLowContrastBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneSemitransparentBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xAA, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);

        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneInactiveBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x33, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneInverseInactiveBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xE5, 0xE5, 0xE5);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneInverseBackgroundBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xDD, 0xDD, 0xDD);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneBorderBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0x99, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 73, 99);
        ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneChromeBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xDD, 0xDD, 0xDD);
    }
```