# Change border color application bar button windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, application-bar

How do I change the application bar from this [image: application bar original]

to be like this

[image: application bar I want].

I already try code like this

`<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="False" Mode="Minimized" BackgroundColor="#01A3BE">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="About" Text="About" IsEnabled="True" Click="About_Click" IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/Icon Navigation.png"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>`

but the border still like picture number 1 with black border. And when I open Blend it just looks like application bar style can not be edited.

Answer (score 1):

The `ApplicationBar` and `ApplicationBarIconButton` are theme aware, they will automatically change their foreground color if you change your phone's theme to light or dark.

To style other elements, you can access the current themes foreground color via

`{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}`

Comment: Well I do want my application doesn't have dependency with device theme. I want it static. Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationBar color is following current phone theme, as also stated in @Gerrit answer. So to force it change to white, you can try applying light theme locally for your application (not changing phone theme entirely) using [PhoneThemeManager](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/).

```
ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();
```

Different ways to force your application displayed in light theme offered as answers to this question [How to force windows phone 8 app to be run in light theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272265/how-to-force-windows-phone-8-app-to-be-run-in-light-theme). And using Jeff Wilcox's `PhoneThemeManager` is the easiest, in my opinion.

Comment: Ok. I found it. What about Accent Color in theme. Can it be edited? I need it because I want to use myy own colors when App bar pressed. And I also found if I use theme manager, my edited background color in application bar forced to use theme from PhoneThemeManager

Comment: Better to open [new questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You have 2 questions, and my answer to the 1st question : currently, I don't know the answer until I try to find out (try google search maybe). to the 2nd, I don't have any idea until I see some of your codes showing how you set background color.

Answer (score 0):

This is what u want

```
this.ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
```

You can create ApplicationBar in code like:

```
ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 52, 73, 94);
ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
```

Hope this helps.