# C#/XAML - Windows Phone 8.1 - Keyboard color

Tags: c#, xaml, keyboard, windows-phone

is it possible to change color of keyboard from black to white. Even if I change RequestTheme to Light (both for page and textblock) the keyboard is still black. All colors changed but keyboard doesn't.

For example in MS's Email app you have white colored keyboard even if your phone's theme is set to black. That's exactly what I want. Maybe it's not part of developer-accessible API.

Thank you.

Comment: That because MS's mail app is setted to Light Theme by default.

Comment: I know, I set theme to light same like they probably did.

Comment: It can't be done with the current API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the theme of your app you can see the accepted answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272265/how-to-force-windows-phone-8-app-to-be-run-in-light-theme). Basically, you can change you theme using ThemeManager mencionated by you.

```
this.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;
```

Or in XAML:

```
<Application
    x:Class="App26.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    RequestedTheme="Light"
    xmlns:local="using:App26">
</Application>
```

Always at application level.

**EDIT**: Keyboard theme changed can't be done with the current API.