# windows phone 8.1 Sliverlight - how to disable black and white theme for app only

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro

in windows phone 8 - we have 2 kind of theme, black and white,

as per this theme, in our app, all control background and all property are changing..

my question is - the app i am developing is theme independent, i want same look and feel in both theme color, whether it is black or white.

what i am trying is set colors for all property - for example, background, foreground, etc

```
BorderBrush="{StaticResource WhiteSolidColorBrush}" Foreground="{StaticResource WhiteSolidColorBrush}"
```

it is the same question asked here, but i am not able to apply in windows phone 8.1 sliverlight-
[Windows phone 8 How to be always on one theme even if phone's theme changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582998/windows-phone-8-how-to-be-always-on-one-theme-even-if-phones-theme-changed?rq=1)

how it is possible ?

Comment: add RequestedTheme="Light/Dark" in application xaml if you want same theme at all phones

Comment: this is only possible for windows phone 8.1 runtime, not for windows phone 8.1 silverlight :)

Comment: I'd just go yank out the Theme related brushes that all your controls inherit from to get their colors and set them to the colors you want to be consistent. I forget what resource dictionary name is they sit in though but probably wouldn't be real hard to find.

Comment: for now i used this one : http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/

Comment: @patel Hi, It seems weird. In my windows phone 8.1 silverlight app I didn't face any problem with _Jeff Wilcox_ `thememanager`. So I want to know where you mentioned the code of using `thememanager` in your project. Please post your code by editing the question or please upload sample application to Dropbox & give us the URL.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options in Silverlight 8.1:

**1:**

Like Chris W. pointed out, JeffWilcox Theme manager overrides the theme resources at runtime (cannot do that in Xaml, sadly).

You can just set the Designer in VS to the Theme you like.

**2:**

The other is to override the default style for the controls you use. Just copy the default style for each control u use and change the color resources in the templates.

You can access the templates either by creating a copy in the editor (Select the control in the outline, click *edit templates* > *edit a copy*, or find them in the SDK folders directly:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Design\System.Windows.xaml*

I personally prefer the second approach. It sounds like a lot of work, but you actually do not use so many controls. Recently used it in a big app end ended up with just overriding 11 control templates (and mostly just changing the colors and font-sizes).

Comment: Why override all of it on a per control basis when you can just toss in overriding brushes/colors based on the names those controls are tied to anyway? So that when say one of the properties in one (or any) of a control goes to look for like `StaticResource BlahPhoneThemeResource` it just inherits from the next logical one you've defined instead of the defaults for that name, seems simpler than editing individual controls on a per need basis.

Comment: Because you can't in Silverlight (Phone 7.5 an newer). At least not in Xaml. If you just do it in code, like the theme manager does, then you won't have support in the visual studio designer.

Comment: Are you positive that I can't override the system resources at the application or even the frameworkelement level in regards to resource inheritance? So I wouldn't be able to just go to a resource dictionary that gets hit *before* the main resourcedictionaries, enter my brushes with the same names and different colors etc and override the system theme resources? I work in SL all day long, but admittedly not SL phone so I'm not 100%, but I am about 98% sure you'd be able to do it just fine. I don't think this OP will reward any bounty either way but for tech. arg. I'm not sure that's correct.

Comment: Well, earliest point to set a brush would be app.xaml, right? If I override PhoneAccentBrush there, it will not be applied anywhere. When I just copy the default styles into a new resource dictionary and merge int into app.xaml, everything is fine. If you know a better solution that works on phone, please give it a shot. :) Would help me a lot, but haven't met anyone who knew a solution so far, sadly...

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not sure what problem you're having with @JeffWilcox theme manager since it looks pretty cool and robust. There's still always the option of overriding those resources explicitly for your app (which is what it looks like his theme manager just gives a much easier way of doing.)

You can find pretty much everything you'll need regarding to this for Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight [in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and the process of implementing what you appear to need is pretty straight forward.